# UIImageView animation is not displayed on view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation

In my Iphone App, I used the following code for the animation of those 3 images in viewDidLoad() method and I use left transform to load this ViewController. But these imageView is not displayed on the view.

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search1.png"],
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"search2.png"],
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"seach3.png"],
                                                    nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc];
[imageView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 60, 60, 30)];
imageView.animationImages = newArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 0.25;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 3;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Please try to put code in a {code} block to make it more legible.

Comment: Obvious question first: have you checked that the [UIImage imageNamed:] calls don't return nil? If the first did, you'd get an entirely empty array so seeing nothing would be the behaviour you'd probably expect.

Answer (score 5):

Animation won't start until you tell it to start. You will need to add a command to startAnimating. I also cleaned up your alloc/init and I added a command to make the image view still keep showing when it is not animating. Setting an animation will not make the image appear. The `image` property is for the still image and the `animationImages` property is for the animating images of a UIImageView.

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 60, 60, 30)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search3.png"]; //This will be the image that is visible when it is NOT animating.


imageView.animationImages = newArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 0.25;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 3;
[imageView startAnimating]; //This will make the animation start

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Finally, your third image is missing an r. I think you want `@"search.png"` and not `@"seach.png"`